# Create envelope using radio button group tag with DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

I have been creating envelopes using DocuSign SOAP API calls.
For one of my clients, I have to create conditional tags based upon the values of the radio button group tag selection.

I am able to create the radio button group tag with a few radio button tags fine but am not able to setup the value for each of the radio button tag. I have assigned the radio button group name for each of the radio button so that the recipient can only select one radio button from the group.

When I setup the conditional tag, I have to provide the parent tag name and the value. Since I am not able to setup the radio button tags with the values, I cannot use the the values in the conditional tags.

I am setting two properties for each of the radio button tag as shown below..

```
tab.value = "cc"
tab.CustomTabRadioGroupName = "paymentmethod"
```

in addition to type, position etc properties. 
Is there any other way to setup the radio button tag values?

Thanks,

Minal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have created a SOAP XML with a radio group having two options Yes and No, when Yes is selected then a Textbox appears, please let me know if it works for you. The trick here is CustomTabType of “Radio” make the TabLabels the same for any radio buttons you want to group together. In below example it is Paymentmethod, and Yes and No are radio options inside Paymentmethod radio group.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:ns="http://www.docusign.net/API/3.0">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
         <ns:Envelope>
           <ns:AccountId>?</ns:AccountId>
            <ns:Documents>
               <ns:Document>
                <ns:ID>32093411</ns:ID>
                <ns:Name>Challenge3.docx</ns:Name>
                <ns:PDFBytes>?</ns:PDFBytes>
                <ns:FileExtension>pdf</ns:FileExtension>
            </ns:Document>
            </ns:Documents>
            <ns:Recipients>
               <ns:Recipient>
                  <ns:ID>45399085</ns:ID>
                  <ns:UserName>Test Radio Name</ns:UserName>
                  <ns:Email>abc@gmail.com</ns:Email>
                  <ns:Type>Signer</ns:Type>
                  <ns:RoutingOrder>1</ns:RoutingOrder>
               </ns:Recipient>
            </ns:Recipients>
            <ns:Tabs>
              <ns:Tab>
                <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
                <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                <ns:XPosition>285</ns:XPosition>
                <ns:YPosition>304</ns:YPosition>
                <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                <ns:Name>Yes</ns:Name>
                <ns:TabLabel>Paymentmethod</ns:TabLabel>
                <ns:CustomTabType>Radio</ns:CustomTabType>
                <ns:CustomTabRequired>true</ns:CustomTabRequired>
                <ns:CustomTabLocked>false</ns:CustomTabLocked>
                <ns:SharedTab>false</ns:SharedTab>
             </ns:Tab>
             <ns:Tab>
                <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
                <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                <ns:XPosition>285</ns:XPosition>
                <ns:YPosition>324</ns:YPosition>
                <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                <ns:Name>No</ns:Name>
                <ns:TabLabel>Paymentmethod</ns:TabLabel>
                <ns:CustomTabType>Radio</ns:CustomTabType>
                <ns:CustomTabRequired>true</ns:CustomTabRequired>
                <ns:CustomTabLocked>false</ns:CustomTabLocked>
            </ns:Tab>
            <ns:Tab>
                <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
                <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                <ns:XPosition>374</ns:XPosition>
                <ns:YPosition>302</ns:YPosition>
                <ns:ScaleValue>10.0</ns:ScaleValue>
                <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                <ns:TabLabel>Text 85a340b8-8159-420c-810a-76926f8c6dad</ns:TabLabel>
                <ns:CustomTabType>Text</ns:CustomTabType>
                <ns:CustomTabWidth>78</ns:CustomTabWidth>
                <ns:CustomTabHeight>11</ns:CustomTabHeight>
                <ns:CustomTabRequired>true</ns:CustomTabRequired>
                <ns:CustomTabLocked>false</ns:CustomTabLocked>
            <ns:CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</ns:CustomTabDisableAutoSize>

        <ns:ConditionalParentLabel>Paymentmethod</ns:ConditionalParentLabel>
                <ns:ConditionalParentValue>Yes</ns:ConditionalParentValue>
                <ns:Font>LucidaConsole</ns:Font>
                <ns:Bold>false</ns:Bold>
                <ns:Italic>false</ns:Italic>
                <ns:Underline>false</ns:Underline>
                <ns:FontColor>Black</ns:FontColor>
                <ns:FontSize>Size9</ns:FontSize>
                <ns:IncludeNoteInEmail>false</ns:IncludeNoteInEmail>
                <ns:IsPaymentAmount>false</ns:IsPaymentAmount>
                <ns:RoundDecimalPlaces>0</ns:RoundDecimalPlaces>
                <ns:MaxLength>4000</ns:MaxLength>
                <ns:RequireAll>false</ns:RequireAll>
            </ns:Tab>
            <ns:Tab>
                <ns:DocumentID>32093411</ns:DocumentID>
                <ns:RecipientID>45399085</ns:RecipientID>
                <ns:PageNumber>1</ns:PageNumber>
                <ns:XPosition>376</ns:XPosition>
                <ns:YPosition>366</ns:YPosition>
                <ns:ScaleValue>1.0</ns:ScaleValue>
                <ns:Type>Custom</ns:Type>
                <ns:TabLabel>Text 5928b009-b2af-4bdb-beb5-62c803fdae0b</ns:TabLabel>
                <ns:CustomTabType>Text</ns:CustomTabType>
                <ns:CustomTabWidth>78</ns:CustomTabWidth>
                <ns:CustomTabHeight>11</ns:CustomTabHeight>
                <ns:CustomTabRequired>true</ns:CustomTabRequired>
                <ns:CustomTabLocked>false</ns:CustomTabLocked>
            <ns:CustomTabDisableAutoSize>false</ns:CustomTabDisableAutoSize>
                <ns:TemplateLocked>false</ns:TemplateLocked>
                <ns:TemplateRequired>false</ns:TemplateRequired>
            <ns:ConditionalParentLabel>Paymentmethod</ns:ConditionalParentLabel>
                <ns:ConditionalParentValue>No</ns:ConditionalParentValue>
                <ns:SharedTab>false</ns:SharedTab>
            <ns:RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>false</ns:RequireInitialOnSharedTabChange>
                <ns:ConcealValueOnDocument>false</ns:ConcealValueOnDocument>
                <ns:Font>LucidaConsole</ns:Font>
                <ns:Bold>false</ns:Bold>
                <ns:Italic>false</ns:Italic>
                <ns:Underline>false</ns:Underline>
                <ns:FontColor>Black</ns:FontColor>
                <ns:FontSize>Size9</ns:FontSize>
                <ns:IncludeNoteInEmail>false</ns:IncludeNoteInEmail>
                <ns:IsPaymentAmount>false</ns:IsPaymentAmount>
                <ns:RoundDecimalPlaces>0</ns:RoundDecimalPlaces>
                <ns:MaxLength>4000</ns:MaxLength>
                <ns:RequireAll>false</ns:RequireAll>
             </ns:Tab>
            </ns:Tabs>
            <ns:Subject>Email Subject Radio</ns:Subject>
            <ns:EmailBlurb>Email Blurb Radio</ns:EmailBlurb>
         </ns:Envelope>
      </ns:CreateAndSendEnvelope>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. You are adding tag value "yes/no" to the name property of the tag here and not the actual value property of the tag. I tried doing the same but I am not getting the value of the radio button tag in the form data. Please advise.

Comment: Which call are you doing to get the form data? In case of radio button value will be X or blank. If Yes is selected then X will return for Yes radio button, else it will be Blank

Comment: I am currently checking the form data from their DocuSign account since I am having issues but I need to use the value in the conditional tags. I cannot specify the "X" for a radio button in that case. I have to get the value from the group.

Comment: I did the conditional tag in the above example, I am showing textbox - Text 85a340b8-8159-420c-810a-76926f8c6dad only when Yes is selected. I have achieved it by using TabLabel of the radiobutton and ns:ConditionalParentLabel and ns:ConditionalParentValue of the textbox

Comment: You have created two separate radio buttons. I need to create radio buttons in a group so that the recipient can only select one option. That is the reason, I have to use the value of the selected radio button in the condition. In your case, the tab labels for both radio buttons are different so they are not part of the group.

Comment: They are part of the group Paymentmethod, and you will be able to select only one option either Yes or No. If Yes selected then only Textbox will appear else Textbox will not appear. Run the above code via SOAPUI after replacing your accountId and PDFBytes, you will see it is working as you are expecting it to be.

Comment: Thank you once again. I did replicate your code and now I am able to create conditional tags based upon the radio button values. Though, if I have to create two different conditional tags based upon yes/no values, I am not able to do so.

Comment: @JuicedTech, Two conditional Tags meaning? Showing one text field when one radio button is selected and showing another text field when another one is selected?

Comment: Yes. That is true. That is what I need to do.

Comment: @JuicedTech: I have update the request XML to show the working of the same i.e Showing one text field when one radio button is selected and showing another text field when another one is selected

Comment: thank you so much for your feedback. I am now able to setup conditional tags based upon the the radio button values.